# Is there anything like USB adapter for RAM?

Tags: usb, memory, adapter

My laptop has only 1 RAM slot. Is there anything like RAM USB adapter so I can plug in another RAM piece for upgrade purpose?

Comment: RAM requires a very fast connection directly to the CPU to be useful. It is possible for OSes to use things like flash drives for swap space or pagefile space, which can improve performance in some cases, but to answer your question, no, there is no way to add actual RAM to your computer without placing it in slots on the motherboard specifically designed for RAM.

Comment: https://downloadmoreram.com/index.html , just kidding.

Comment: There have been similar questions that seem to focus solely on data retention capabilities, and therefore equate RAM with Flash and other mass storage.  The CPU can access the contents of a RAM location simply by specifying an address, i.e. that is how instructions are fetched.  The supporting computer hardware accomplishes that.  Whereas obtaining data from a peripheral device over a bus requires execution of dozens of instructions to perform multiple I/O operations.  Simply using an OS and/or high-level programming language will give you an incomplete understanding of computers.

Comment: It would be like using a deposit box in the next city as your pocket.